# Three point functions, fusion and braiding in CFT

Tags: conformal-field-theory, representation-theory, correlation-functions

Maybe someone could give some pointers. If I understand correctly, a rational CFT can be determined completely determined in terms of the braiding and fusion matrices. On the other hand, one should be able to determine the theory in terms of the two and three point functions. Hence, in particular, I would expect that it is possible to express the three-point function coefficients in terms of fusion and braiding matrices. Do you know if there is an explicit expression for this? In a related question, do you know if there is an equation analogous to the [Verlinde formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlinde_algebra) for the fusion coefficients but for the three-point function coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, there are infinitely many rational CFTs which give equivalent Modular Tensor Categories, i.e. the equivalent fusion and braiding matrices.
One can simply take the tensor product with the theory associated with an even self-dual lattice.

If you know the lowest weights you can probably tell more.

Also braiding matrices are more related to 4-point functions.